# "libpython3.5m.a: 0654-200 Cannot open the specified file" Error while compiling Python3 in AIX

Tags: python-3.x, aix

I have tried to compile Python3 in AIX7.1.

I just follow simple two steps.

```
./configure 
make
```

However, while compiling it returns error.

```
nm: libpython3.5m.a: 0654-200 Cannot open the specified file.
nm: No such file or directory
ld: 0711-596 SEVERE ERROR: Object Python/ceval.o
        An RLD for section 2 (.data) refers to symbol 0,
        but the storage class of the symbol is not C_EXT or C_HIDEXT.
```

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an older discussion of this problem at

https://bugs.python.org/issue9799

Seems it might be an issue with the xlc compiler's implementation of computed gotos.

The solution was to turn this option off via --without-computed-gotos

```
./configure --without-computed-gotos
```